# How to do SMARTS reaction substructure mapping with RDKit

Tags: python, rdkit, cheminformatics, smiles

I have been trying to use the RDKit's reaction substructure matching for some time. I want to match all reactions where a C-H bond is being broken to form a new C-C bond.

This is my code:

```py
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import rdChemReactions

c_h_template = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts('[#6:1]-[#1]>>[#6:1]~[#6]')
x = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts('C1=[CH:1]C=CC=C1.C[CH:2]=C.[Pd]>>C[C:2](=C)[CH:1]1=CC=CC=C1',useSmiles=True)
result = rdChemReactions.HasReactionSubstructMatch(x,c_h_template)
print(result) # always False
```

The result is always False, even though the reaction pattern should match.

The template, and the reaction are shown below (in jupyter notebook):

[image: picture of jupyter nptebook]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have read about SMARTS from daylight website, and I think the atom mapping is correct, and it should match. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @S R Maiti if my post answer your question, could you please mark it using the tick next to it?

Comment: @VandanRevanur I have discovered after some testing that RDKit's SMARTS implementation seems to be bugged, and gives inconsistent answers so there really is no answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the `c_h_template` to also use smiles and the substructMatch returns **True**.

I am using rdkit version number: **2022.9.4**

Here is the full reproducible code.

```
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import rdChemReactions
c_h_template = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts('[CH:1]>>[C:1]~[C:2]', useSmiles=True)
rxn = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts('C1=[CH:1]-C=CC=C1.C[CH:2]=C.[Pd]>>C[C:2](=C)[CH:1]1=CC=CC=C1',useSmiles=True)

result = rdChemReactions.HasReactionSubstructMatch(x,c_h_template)
print(result) # returns True
```